# Problems with for and for each loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am setting up a loop and i don't know what code to put in.

Below the code runs but at the end all the cells that have had a hyperlink inserted show cell 173 when there should be a link to cell 32 in the first cell then cell 47 in second and so on. I can see the problem but not sure on what to do.

```
Sub Hyperlink()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim t1 As ListObject
Set t1 = Range("Testtbl").ListObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim p As String

Set rng = Range("CourseName")

For Each cell In rng
    For i = 1 To t1.ListRows.Count
        If t1.ListColumns("UnLockedField").DataBodyRange(i) = "H" Then
            p = t1.ListColumns("UnLockedField").DataBodyRange(i).Address

            With cell
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, _
                    Address:="", _
                    SubAddress:=p
            End With
        End If
    Next i
Next cell
End If
0:
End Sub
```

I am hoping that each cell in the range will have its on link to the cell that i needs to go to.

Comment: Where do you define `rng`?

Comment: Updated to show the range. I stripped some code and forgot to leave it in.

Comment: Your range object needs to be a cell, a row, a column or a selection of cells e.g ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B2"). See the docs for range: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)

Comment: Have you stepped through to see what's going on? Is 173 the last value? You appear potentially to be adding several hyperlinks to each cell so only the last will be recorded.

Comment: @bm13563 The range shows to a selection of cell.

Comment: @SJR I have. It loops through i for the first cell then at the end, it goes to the next cell and restarts i again. 173 is the last cell with "H" so it records that.

Comment: Therein lies your problem. I don't really understand what you're trying to do. You might want to post a screenshot illustrating what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've edited your code to indent it properly. It makes it easier to see what's going on with it and reveals an extra `End If` near the end

Comment: What is the point of the label `0:`?

Comment: !(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kr-eDUlf9JLBzWmnu0ldVjyv4pvHwII_). Here is the image of the spreadsheet. As you can see, the current links all go to C31 when they should link to different cells.

Comment: @JohnColeman Its to do with code that i have stripped out for here

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank You